# Copy one column to another in different table mysql

Tags: mysql

I write following query but it is not working it shows Query interrupted

```
update media m ,cities c
    set m.latitude=c.latitude
    where m.cities_id=c.id;
```

anyone can know what is mistake in above query???

Comment: It also depends on what you're trying to achieve, if `media.latitude` is not populated at all, you can do `insert into ... select` type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternate syntax that allow for joins in an update but this is the standard SQL way. Make sure the inner query only returns a single value.

```
update media
set latitude = (
    select c.latitude from cities c where c.id = media.cities_id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query :

```
UPDATE media m LEFT JOIN cities c on c.cities_id = m.id SET m.latitude=c.latitude;
```

Note: ensure Both cities_id , id are of same datatype.

Comment: Thnx for the comment changed it

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE media m 
    INNER JOIN cities c ON m.cities_id=c.id
 SET m.latitude=c.latitude;